# Compute the remainder when $67!$ is divided by $71$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is how far I've been able to get.

By using **[Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem):**

$$\begin{align}
70! &\equiv -1 \pmod{71} \\
67!(68)(69)(70) &\equiv -1 \pmod{71} \\
67!(68)(69)(-1) &\equiv -1 \pmod{71} \\
67!(68)(69) &\equiv 1 \pmod{71} \\
\end{align}$$

**EDIT:** Here is how I proceeded using TMM's and  Carl Mummert's hints.

$$\begin{align}
&68 \equiv -3 \pmod{71}\\
and\\
&69 \equiv -2 \pmod{71}\\
\end{align}$$

So:
$$\begin{align}
67!(-3)(-2) &\equiv 1 \pmod{71} \\
67! &\equiv 6^{-1} \pmod{71} \\
\end{align}$$

By using the **[Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)**:
$$71 = 6 \cdot 11 + 5$$
$$6 = 5 \cdot 1 + 1$$
$$5 = 1 \cdot 5 + 0$$

Now, going backwards:
$$\begin{align}
1 &= 6 - 5 \\
&= 6 - (71 - 6 \cdot 11) \\
&= 6 + 6(11) - 71 \\
&= 6(1 + 11) - 71(1) \\
&= 6(12) - 71(1)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $67! \equiv 6^{-1} \equiv 12 \pmod{71}$.

Comment: So $67! = 69^{-1}68^{-1}\pmod{71}$. Compute those two inverses and you're done.

Comment: You should consider using $ \cdot $ instead of $*$ to denote multiplication for two reasons. Typically, $*$ denotes convolution and $*$ looks ugly when you use it for multiplication.

Comment: The first steps can be condensed by replacing -1 with 70 right at the outset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $$69 \equiv -2 \pmod{71}, \qquad 68 \equiv -3\pmod{71}.$$ 
Further hint: $72 = 6 \cdot 12$, so the inverse you need to compute should not be too difficult...

Comment: Great, thanks.  I used the the Euclidean algorithm backwards to find the inverse of 6 mod 71.  Also worked out to be 12.

Comment: @icanc: For small numbers it usually helps to just try and see. As the inverse $x$ of $6$ must be between $1$ and $70$, we must have $6 \leq 6x \leq 420$ and therefore $6x \in \{72, 143, 214, 285, 356\}$. We can already eliminate the two odd numbers, and if necessary check the other three by hand.

Comment: (That of course does not mean that you should not know the Euclidean algorithm. But sometimes it's easier to be smart and lazy...)

Answer (score 6):

Recall that if 
$$xy \equiv a \pmod{n}$$
then
$$x \equiv ay^{-1} \pmod{n}$$ if $y$ is invertible in $\pmod{n}$. In your case, $n$ is $71$ a prime, which guarantees that any $y \not \equiv 0 \pmod{71}$ is invertible in $\pmod{71}$. Hence,, we have
$$67! \times 68 \times 69 \equiv 1 \pmod{71} \implies 67! \equiv (69)^{-1} (68)^{-1} \pmod{71}$$
We have
\begin{align}
68 \times 47 - 71 \times 45 & = 1\\
69 \times 35 - 71 \times 34 & = 1
\end{align}
Hence,
$$(68)^{-1} \equiv 47 \pmod{71} \text{ and }(69)^{-1} \equiv 35 \pmod{71}$$
Hence,
$$67!\equiv 35 \times 47 \pmod{71} \equiv 12 \pmod{71}$$